# Boost hana first successful sfinae

Tags: c++, boost-hana

I'd like to execute the first lambda in a list of lambdas, which isn't sfinaed out with boost hana.
I have succeeded doing that with `hana::if_` but that doesn't scale to any number of lambdas.
I think I want lazy evaluation of `find_if` but I don't seem to grasp the [documentation](https://boostorg.github.io/hana/structboost_1_1hana_1_1lazy.html) of `hana` well enough to find the right syntax.
This is where you could tell me I am trying to solve it the wrong way or help me find a syntax that allows me to evaluate lazily.

You can find a live example with all of the code from this question on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z: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%2Bh5gtFktl93RmPIK4Tqcz%2BfNnedymnr1Vms7FulgC074fLy95d7389ZdmFJPAqEtNMf1jICQKES1aFQAgEF8YAIBHJIgwbMN0FbOhqmlWZ5kfGNNx0ZU8zdXQ/QDdCx0vadZ2QBdsLVPC/GIPtKL/TUSO4Qly30V1/37YE/xEmk6QZZgmWhVl2S5Hk%2BQFIURTFCVWNCTkHAZVNFVIlipTYzVtQIXUDSNHMTRAM1HCtG1PlIjt6GPAdvWHai6Aw2hQ1pCNCijSDY3JVdkw3DMHLvPdeIPX09OcytMGrYha3PTCmzfeZXwi51uz/DjTyHYs0I82jJ3o%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%2BNGHZtFE32vXXzfTG37490x19xENUxwyPzV3B2Qoz5cvHVNptjl5hJqQobsvSgR2BAGEVwEjk1TC6MAYBKqYEfvCcMUC8AwJXqvB6l8UCLBMtCaESptByh2HgJGWspJJB2FQKU7AN47GwMg5%2BgoYS6mLBcOERCu5lwOIQpBT8fJoIwWWXhBwiGa13AQIQmogg%2BlISZC4HIdDaGZIQyB0DYHcMegQsRODPCsHGn%2BTKIgHaxhwWgOROibBEJIWQ7SkjKF0B2EIBwyAVjhlQco1RuiCAbxAPowxcNYb%2BTnkpReBBNLaRXqY5xvir4Ih3nfbAB9X4ny/mvOJVkt6Ilvnve%2B/CUHoFSe/T%2BcNz7KXxmpImxBImHUAR/EBpCqDgPUeg2BOx4GIKYYIjRmCYkX0yRY/BojrHKNqZ8OxWVHE/VoeGEADDumLlYb6Dh9ltCn3HtHKxD8BGoN6SImwhCvHc2kUSORhA4xKPWd46xrThFaKgtsvR1gDHlKMWUEx/EiLmLwTcoh4zSHkIcRUZxrj3FYHQFcLxTzMkBLeUE14CLEaSWkqjVQckMb4hxjsU4AAqZFyNdRIQ5EIYshAwBSA5PBEyzB6b0jwOwV8xBiAkCJHqHYWAaEOFYAQXFpwFLz11OiCJJMyaNywYBHBcJr45JsLvfeh93TH1PmUlyUrsmJLyckgpzDilAPSXzFSBNW7E20mKqm9TgHjTARAoR7TOl%2BR2YUu1fSvnYMGb87ZYySaAvsU6aZ1DZn0MYbslhbC4ycOUQ82M2ydU9LadEr11yTkyPOQotk4jtl3M0Zs56MK/Fwpcu81gnyTzur8UMv53rtK%2BqmSClxbjMAeMhdCkZsSC0vMCSEmerwXi7x2DtXwiay2AXCcvRp4Txkr3GqcU4Ox8SoHRDsaldKYgMswKeWdQqBjjPNdO32f4pDzFYNIbg8hXCyHkKgaQhy9AGGcYsZYazCicHkAQaQcgCKkDnCAF9VxIgAA5XScEiDIMDKoZDhBVLwE9Uhwjno/Ve6Q8ghAgBkKQd9l75hwFgEgNA9L2BkAoDhAjvRgCcAo3wBltJiCoYgEERDpAgjJmIHqaQr7SD4ckQAeVoKwNjl7SBYB2uodgjH8B/FaHCVDgmkEtB9KsOQ5B6BlEY6wPAQRVqsbsFgRjK0yHsaPXwVQwAhAADU8CYAAO7ccNBejj/BGAsDE5wEojnhBiEkIJpQJRVDqBQAYAwKgNOodgMzDgxIBikDhGEKQnBlTwew%2BFkAwBjjAHYOE6LvQ4ucE/fMS6Mn3zr0jFoO9ehXM7HfNxwoKGHStAsGrWw9gGjKE8F0PIBR0jxESHQYYrhRgZB67QdrPQwijGaPVyo4w%2BvKAmxUdotQRvTDG2MDoM3xvjCW51zg8xSVLBWFwY9p6EOCevVIcQAHlTvgSzsYAbidgUauJwcBt7MyGAYfgBESoX2ajsKR4g33wizDfYhr9P7ihXGVK6SI4RXTKnh%2BEGQyptCI%2BVCoaQ8HSBOC4GB0gF6lNnZQ2hjDoPSA4cQP48Q8mETkEoDUUzog1BlAYAgVAVn7PyHw2uxkSRGd%2BFYCztn%2BPOeoH%2BylijowufruINxn0gv2eMbk8gZ4xBTPIY8FT5AVR8AXvkI5pgbAOCub4LhDzEhGNKFGH5jQgW9DBaCKFqAyXIsECy7F%2BLiX8vHUK8VvypW3sVaqzVhY%2B2jdjB13z5nrOFdxfkFZ1aMRDNHakGevHjGzuMOp6yi7V2bt3eQA9zgT2Xu2/e7gQgrL1g7ZB1h%2BY4PChXEKE35vLeW/o7gydgn6vUPocw3l9v2hO9IakDX/vMWEgWHCEAA%3D%3D%3D).

Example:
Say I want to implement a generic `addToContainer` function

```cpp
template <class T>
void addToContainerIf(T &container, const typename T::value_type &element) {
  auto optional_inserted =
      hana::sfinae([&element](auto &c) { return c.insert(end(c), element); });
  auto optional_push_backed = hana::sfinae([&element](auto &c) {
    c.push_back(element);
    return end(c)--;
  });
  hana::if_(
      hana::is_nothing(optional_inserted(container)),
      [&] { optional_push_backed(container); }, [] {});
}
```

This is supposed to behave as follows and it does:

```cpp
void testIf() {
  std::vector<int> v{1, 2};
  std::vector<int> expected{1, 2, 3};
  addToContainerIf(v, 3);
  if (v.size() != expected.size()) {
    std::cout << "If implementation failed: Expected v to have "
              << expected.size() << " elements, but it has " << v.size()
              << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "If implementation succeeded." << std::endl;
}
```

Now I'd like to change `addToContainerIf` such that it uses a hana::tuple to find the first lambda that is `hana::just`:

```cpp
template <class T>
void addToContainerTuple(T &container, const typename T::value_type &element) {
  auto optional_inserted =
      hana::sfinae([&element](auto &c) { return c.insert(end(c), element); });
  auto optional_push_backed = hana::sfinae([&element](auto &c) {
    c.push_back(element);
    return end(c)--;
  });
  hana::find_if(
      hana::transform(hana::make_tuple(optional_inserted, optional_push_backed),
                      [&](auto f) { return f(container); }),
      hana::is_just);
}
```

However this fails with

```
Value of: v
Expected: equals { 1, 2, 3 }
  Actual: { 1, 2, 3, 3 }
```

Because both `insert` and `push_back` exist on `std::vector`.

So, instead, I'd like hana to lazily evaluate the sfinaes.

I have tried the following, but I don't understand the [documentation](https://boostorg.github.io/hana/structboost_1_1hana_1_1lazy.html) well enough to find the correct syntax for what I want to achieve.

This fails to compile:

```cpp
template <class T>
void addToContainerTupleLazy(T &container, const typename T::value_type &element) {
  auto optional_inserted =
      hana::sfinae([&element](auto &c) { return c.insert(end(c), element); });
  auto optional_push_backed = hana::sfinae([&element](auto &c) {
    c.push_back(element);
    return end(c)--;
  });
  hana::eval(
      hana::find_if(
          hana::transform(hana::make_tuple(optional_inserted, optional_push_backed),
                          [&](auto f) { return hana::make_lazy(f)(container); }),
          hana::make_lazy(hana::is_just)
      )
  );
}
```

Please see the godbolt link for the compilation error.

Comment: Did you try `boost::hana::overload_linearly`?

Answer (score 0):

I found a [solution](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAVlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrRDbSV9ABk8tTADlnACNMYhAAFgBOUgAHVCFCc1o7Rxc3WPjEuh8/QKcQsKijTBMzOgYCZmICFOdXd2NMUySKqoIcgODQiOihSuratIb%2B9t9O/O6ogEojVAdiZA4pHQBmX2RHLABqTRWbINR4ggB6BDVmADoEGJjd7E0ZAEFV9c3MHb3zPuJMZic7h7PbRrWgbBzbXY2ABuTSIxABT0BtD%2BmCEMWYiy2Z2RHwAIlsDkcQCBscxdvpEU8CJgnDFVNSPjYNswhEItgAVBGPKGoPDoLbMdDodmoOz0ZhjYgASSoEHZO20ADY0OLJaQtiq%2BlsCABPGJWFEc4lQtgOTAAfV1%2BoVipKNKsBCmOwA7BTHlsBQ4iFtUDEysjWObfCJqph%2BbtcYCPdGsediUIqL5mJgIJpuPolXanA607iIMwvagbcgnZpXVsfgR5rQNRdg6ECBBPBAS%2Bqsw6puSXbjOys3R6C97ff62OaYg4hAhzUEMQBrMN42PI%2BOJ5EptMZ23sbP0XP5wvF0uuqPR5AXceT6dzpvbjvkk8eyvVrbNksAWjf96eHrLPa/7qXZhiTwKhzVTb8Y0A4ChHNWhUAIBBfGACBhySUd61DdAWzoSpJSmGYH2jDcdEVXMXV0H0/TQwMLynGdkHnLCVVwvxiF7Cjf3VYjuHxMt9GdP8%2B0BX9hKpGk6WYBlIWZVkOS5Hk%2BQFIURTFFjQnZBw6RTeUSOYiVWPVTUCG1PUDWzI0QBNRwLStd4SPbegj37T0hyouh0NoENqXDFZIwgmNSRXJN13Tezb13Hj929XSnIrTAq2IGszwwxtXxmF9wsdLtf3Yk9ByLVD3Joic6LnBcIygkAE2C1NQszTK93yw9yMIs9aKvBib3tRz/xjJ9EpfawWymD9eu7XKIMCkBV3QINZUIj0poIYg1ATEgnAgKanGYedLU09gULcgMg08hsw3VQrjva%2BjGII/zIIex6djq0jIqaqhYv6mtZT0vDsoEu6AICuMQDwGCFAnLKhMRATRMealaXpOy9hktlORWe4ngU/lBWFUUcP09T9swLxmAALx1OViwJtUFqe%2BnHqMkz9WRcz2WNU0bNMm0HMdFqIKay6PK88rfOezdecag8Yv5oG4oSpK61O6omyG1sMu6qHnJE6GAMFo7R2usqfN4l7Jbe6WlRLWWYzakqOtnLqdy1wivsGpiRs/XWf1h3WTyWlbPJoYgNrpqaZrmzaQe23aqy0w6R0DFLzsoxOx3tm6w0BhmGeIpUpe9D7yPl58prB80rL5agpmw1VWPY8bSDpvPXrzd7Pvi58fpp%2Bv/sEt0RMpbleX5ak%2BhlCAnJPPp0GNWESEhXwCDuLYoT4zh1W0HXnJnufTAXz5dwxl9xH1Uww3Xzf1RWbe8uU/G69CCeoWviaAJArYIChC4EjJlMnTAGACqmBT6wjDD/PAf9J5T3urvFAcxjKQkhAqbQMoth4ERprSSSQthUAlOwWeWxsCgPPvyKE2oixnBhCgumT0kF7BPmfbyECoGlj2MgnQ2gNbOyEOqIIXp0HGTOGyThjJkHf1/v/Whj16E2C2HAzwrAxq/gyiIG20Y4FoAEbIlBaCMFaWdtgug8iHDIEWGGcBoidEKOsEo723ZhKwyxiPbUqICAaXjjAgCcCYT73hIfZex816ug3lsLevsd4EFnpZee/ibBLxXiAphF8QlXy2DfCJd88aqUJsQDxB0X7pLfh6D%2BX8WH/y2IA4BJDmGSOgeoj0miEFiIYZw/J7x9GZSMd9fBYYQBEJqQuch3oqF2W0Fve6ud2EMKSWA9A5TJ4tLkaI3mvCCQCMILGER4ylmrwWZ2SZ9NrFROJIo5RAlVF2WPLAk58DtHTOWeM9p6DMGGP9CYsxmALHzKsQ8%2BRtyzn2MHs8Jx8NxJI0ZKjOSvlsZbGOAAKgRhJBkCEwbyKLIQMAUg2RwWMswDUqBaR4HYC%2BYgxASAEh1FsLAeCHCsAIPC448kXFj3ccTUmFNFl8Wnrc3xcJF5H2wKvS%2BYTb4QR8bEgVgShWzNISK9w6SxV63vjkyU7SOWU0KSsYp6CqCfwkZAipVSxaytqYa%2Bp3KbnRK0Ygv5bTiYvIMQ6bpuDemEOIckshFDYzUM4dIh6OjTXgLqWwmwHCdmrL4RsoRLIUG7INaw/1kFjnRMBdrC5JQ1GWrlk0%2B5YbWlPIdZ0rB7yhCmPMVgH5OyU2nNsecvyIKG2AiXlsbavguXXIAqyieOrWXtMnmNY4xwti4lQKiLYuKCVEvYCePt7LyaUzfr%2BKQMxWDSG4PIVwsh5CoGkGGvQBh0XzExKsTg8gCDSDkPhUgs43ArAuJESIMgViRG0NwGQnBIjcBWO4NdUhwibsvTu6Q8ghAgBkKQC926ZhwFgEgNA07QjkEoAhmIxLujAE4FhvgxLqTEDAxAIIQHSBBCTMQHU0gz2kAQ87AA8rQVgFHt2kCwNtdQ7BiP4B%2BM0GEYHmMgKaF6JYchyD0BKMR1geAggrXI3YLAxHloYMoyuvgqhgBCAAGp4EwAAd1oyzZTfAcJMDYBwTg4QjOCBEBIYjSgLOqHUCgAwBgVBSbA7AVmHBCR9FIDCMIUhOCKgAzBzzIBgCHGAOwVlvnugBc4FemYl0%2BNvhnhGLQB69Dma2G%2BWjKxQN2maBYVWth7B1GUJ4DoeQCjKDiAkf0gxXAb1q1kWglWuhhA3o0QrtBWgDFK2kTrBX/S9dGLkdryg%2BhtAaxNkYbWJgdZmEIOYCwzOrvXYB5ju6pDiAAByKjfEFrYwAzFbCwxcTgn990ZkMEQ/AcIFQrFCXYRDxAHvhCmOeoD17b1KguDIGQkRFQyGdFEHbMhwiKjB7wP9AHSBOC4P90gW6RNbdA%2BByDX3SCwcQCAATyBCxkAoPmYg6nRBqBKAwBAqAdNbqo6h4l3Syd%2BFYJT6nyP5D0/YGETD2HOehFo16VnNPiN48eCTvj8g8cVHwFu%2BQ/BGAsA4%2BZyzBBhBiEkMxpQG8HMaGc3oVzQR3NQFC95ggMX/OBeC4lo6yXUu%2BXS9drLOW8uzGPWZowUTfBM4p1T4XAX5A6ZWjEZTa2pAbqR8RrbxDBP3d2/tw7x3kCnc4Ody7eubu4EIBS09H2MfQZmD97gFxHuRHCDt8vnBnQ7ciJwFYzpf3SFh%2Bz0gqOjDo6g1erHMAcdEHsMh4n6mQOkCqKT8nLPfeGb54UDwd2SDKHlyZpXFn5dq5s8xpw7k0CZ7hAACRZLoL5tBHiFn01YPp/u4eb9QNvkgp/afyA38iNA0vfCGZnq/qQoHPe0G9%2BPtnhne9WApRZ5mR1Bg5toCBloHBaBZxSBA9mBg9/dQ9w9m8ttQDgA3xwDJI3stgdNCAEAtg48DtwgjsTszsqMO8V0C83BwgLhIcZBuAsNOAdttB4s9ttAdsVBG8NsUch8wMINKDr0/1tAeDgNP888EtzcEgLBwggA%3D%3D%3D) myself, by not using `hana::sfinae`, but instead `hana::is_valid`:

```cpp
template <class T>
void addToContainerTupleLazy(T &container,
                             const typename T::value_type &element) {
  auto optional_inserted = [&element](auto &c) {
    return c.insert(end(c), element);
  };
  auto optional_push_backed = [&element](auto &c) {
    c.push_back(element);
    return end(c)--;
  };

  hana::transform(
      hana::find_if(hana::make_tuple(optional_inserted, optional_push_backed),
                    [&](auto f) { return hana::is_valid(f)(container); }),
      [&](auto f) { return f(container); });
}
```